# Autologin on https with json-data POST

Tags: php, json, forms, post, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert form data to JS object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

I need to login my users to external website, but there's a problem, this website processes only json-data POST values, ex. {"username":"user","password":"12345"}

```
<form action="https://external.com/login" method="POST">
<input name="username" value="user" />
<input name="password" value="12345" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This above only sends average key=value data, how can I use  to POST json-data to external https?

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jquery example using [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

HTML:

```html
<form action="https://external.com/login" method="POST" onsubmit="return postJson(this)">
<input name="username" value="user" />
<input name="password" value="12345" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JQ:

```js
function postJson(form) {
    var action = $(form).attr('action');
    var user = $('[name="username"]', form).val();
    var pass = $('[name="password"]', form).val();

    console.log('action=' + action + ', user=' + user + ', pass=' + pass);

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ username: user, password: pass }),
        success: function(data, status) {
            // do something after login
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNhBs/1/)

Comment: does this work for external donain?

Comment: @user1482261 No, for cross domain you must use JSONP, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506208/1741542

Comment: I tried jsonp, but had problems with POST in jsonp =(